# Selecting cell based on another cell's value

Tags: google-sheets, cell

I don't know if this is possible, although I looked and did not find a solution to this:

```
=PV!A(Results!c2)
```

I have a field PV which has a lot of values in it on column A.

Results, has results from a race. I am trying to get the cell in column A depending on what the value is in Results. Is this possible?

Comment: so `Results!c2` returns a row number?

Comment: @ScottCraner Results!c2 Returns a int like 5 or 6

Comment: and that is the row in column A you want returned?

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX:

```
=INDEX(PV!A:A,Results!c2)
```